# Particionamento em C

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer uma atividade na qual devo digitar na entrada o tamanho do vetor, a posição do pivô dele, e depois digitar os elementos que compõem esse vetor

**exemplo de entrada:**

- 7 - tamanho do vetor
- 1 - pivo dele
- 78 - aqui ja começa os elementos
- 43- no caso esse seria o pivo
- 23
- 98
- 32
- 13
- 77

  **Saida:**
- 23
- 32
- 13
- **43**
- 98
- 78
- 77

A saida tem que conter os numeros menores que o pivo em cima dele e os maiores do abaixo dele, sem ser necessario estarem ordenados, mas o meu codigo esta dando "Segmentation Fault" n sei pq, alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  int  n, i, p;
  printf("Tamanho do vetor\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

        int arr[n];

   printf("Pivô do vetor\n");     
    scanf("%d",&p);

  printf("elementos do vetor\n");
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

}

particiona(arr, 0, n-1, p);

  printf("saida\n");
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);

  return 0;
}





int particiona(int *V, int inicio, int final, int p ){
    int esq, dir, pivo, aux;
    esq = inicio;
    dir = final;

pivo = V[p];


while(esq < dir){
     while(V[dir] >= pivo && esq<dir)
        dir--;
        if(esq<dir){
            V[esq] = V[dir];
        }
    while(V[esq] <= pivo && esq<dir)
        esq++;

    if(esq<dir){
            V[dir] = V[esq];
        }


    }
       V[esq] = pivo;

         return esq;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta posicionar a função particiona() antes da função main(). Do jeito que vc fez tem que declarar a função pra usá-la. Se vc escrever a função antes do main() não precisa declarar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int particiona(int *V, int inicio, int final, int p )
{
    int esq, dir, pivo, aux;
    esq = inicio;
    dir = final;
    pivo = V[p];
    while(esq < dir)
    {
        while(V[dir] >= pivo && esq<dir)
        dir--;
        if(esq<dir)
        {
            V[esq] = V[dir];
        }
        while(V[esq] <= pivo && esq<dir) esq++;
        if(esq<dir)
        {
            V[dir] = V[esq];
        }
        V[esq] = pivo;
    }
    return esq;
}
int main()
{
    int  n, i, p;
    printf("Tamanho do vetor\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Pivô do vetor\n");     
    scanf("%d",&p);
    printf("elementos do vetor\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    particiona(arr, arr[0], arr[n-1], p);
    printf("saida\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Saída no terminal]

Comment: hmm agr rodou mas ainda n ta printando certo, o print ta saindo igual a entrada, :/

Answer (score 0):

Algo desse tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, p;
    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Posicao do pivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    int vetor[n];
    printf("Digite os %d valores do vetor\n",n);
    for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
    {
        if (a!=p) printf("%d- ",a+1);
        else printf("%d* ",a+1);
        scanf("%d",&vetor[a]);
    }
    int dir[n/2], esq[n/2], iD=0, iE=0;
    for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
    {
        if ((vetor[a] < vetor[p]) && (a != p))
        {
            esq[iE]=vetor[a];
            iE++;
        }
        else if (a != p)
        {
            dir[iD]=vetor[a];
            iD++;
        }
    }
    for (int a=0; a<iE; a++) printf("%d ", esq[a]);
    printf("|%d| ", vetor[p]);
    for (int a=0; a<iD; a++) printf("%d ", dir[a]);
}
```

[image: Saída no terminal]